# add(object) extended from ArrayAdapter is not being overridden. Because of it I am unable to call that mtd

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, overriding

I am getting an error as "ERROR: Method cannot override method from superclass" for the add() method from the ArrayAdapter class. Removing the annotation is not helping.

```
package com.example.den_2.json_example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    public ContactAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override // ERROR: Method cannot override method from superclass
    public void add(Contacts object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row = convertView;
        ContactHolder contactHolder;

        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            contactHolder = new ContactHolder();
            contactHolder.tx_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_name);
            contactHolder.tx_email = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_email);
            contactHolder.tx_mobile = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_mobile);
            row.setTag(contactHolder);
        }
        else{
            contactHolder = (ContactHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Contacts contacts = (Contacts) this.getItem(position);
        contactHolder.tx_name.setText(contacts.getName());
        contactHolder.tx_email.setText(contacts.getEmail());
        contactHolder.tx_mobile.setText(contacts.getMobile());
        return row;
    }

    static class ContactHolder
    {
        TextView tx_name, tx_email, tx_mobile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter for your use:

```
    public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private List<Contacts> list = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
            private Context mContext;
            public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<Contacts> list) {
                this.mContext=context;
                this.list=list;
            }

           /* @Override // ERROR: Method cannot override method from superclass
            public void add(Contacts object) {
                super.add(object);
                list.add(object);
            }*/
//Your custom add Function for this adapter
            public void add(Contacts object){
                list.add(object);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return list.size();
            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Contacts getItem(int position) {
                return list.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row;
                row = convertView;
                ContactHolder contactHolder;

                if(row==null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
                    contactHolder = new ContactHolder();
                    contactHolder.tx_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_name);
                    contactHolder.tx_email = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_email);
                    contactHolder.tx_mobile = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_mobile);
                    row.setTag(contactHolder);
                }
                else{
                    contactHolder = (ContactHolder) row.getTag();
                }

                Contacts contacts = (Contacts) this.getItem(position);
                contactHolder.tx_name.setText(contacts.getName());
                contactHolder.tx_email.setText(contacts.getEmail());
                contactHolder.tx_mobile.setText(contacts.getMobile());
                return row;
            }

            static class ContactHolder
            {
                TextView tx_name, tx_email, tx_mobile;
            }
        }
```

Comment: But isn't the add() method of ArrayAdapter class overridable?

Comment: No, you can user add() function of arrayAdapter like adapter.add(someObject). But cannot override it.

Comment: So you mean to say I can invoke that function through an object but i cannot override it? So, while creating that method I shouldn't annotate it with @overridable? Wouldn't that show an error?

Comment: You cannot override as well make function with same fun name & params in ArrayAdapter.

Comment: But I did so for the other functions of arrayadapter class like getcount() and getItem() and others

Answer (score 0):

Do not override it. Just use composition and call add method of arrayadapter in your own add method.

Comment: I do not understand. Should i remove the annotations so that it is my own method? And then inside it I should insert that add method?